# Custom Villager with potions as trade

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So I'm trying to make a custom trade villager with potions as one of the trades. But I can't seem to figure out what to put in the command block.

What I've got so far is:

```
sell:{id:"minecraft:potion",Count:1}}
```

Can someone help me with this command?

I'm playing on version 1.9

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Comment: Yes, I have tried to solve this problem but I can't seem figure it out.

Comment: @Frank I think Meta.SE said those comments weren't really allowed anymore...

Comment: sell:{id:"minecraft:potion",Count:1}} that's part of the command I want help with. I know that if I put that the villager will trade me a mundane potion, but I want him to trade a strength potion; and I don't know what else to put.

Answer (score 2):

In 1.9, potions no longer rely on the damage value of the potion item to determine what type of default potion it is. Instead, the `Potion` string tag holds a [string-based default potion ID](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Potion#Item_data), which is stored in the `tag` compound:

```
sell:{id:"minecraft:potion",Count:1,tag:{Potion:"minecraft:strength"}}}
```

If instead you want to sell a potion with custom effects, you would use the old `CustomPotionEffects` list (using an [effect ID](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Status_effect#List_of_effects)):

```
sell:{id:"minecraft:potion",Count:1,tag:{CustomPotionEffects:[{Id:5,Duration:600}]}}}
```